# How do I find the routes associated with a stop using GTFS?

Tags: mysql, gtfs

So I'm building a transit application that provides me a with a stop_id on a database. How do I find the buses that services that stop?
Ex: buses 10 and 23 passes through stop_id# 1234
I tried the query below but it only provides me with one bus every time

```
select distinct r.route_short_name
from routes r, trips t, stop_times st
where r.route_id = t.route_id
and t.trip_id = st.trip_id
and st.stop_id =
```

I checked my gtfs files to find that stop_id# 1234 has two different buses servicing it. I also tried it without the DISTINCT and it just lists the same bus repeatedly. Any comments/help/ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right idea, but you ought to be joining tables together instead. Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.route_short_name
    FROM stop_times st
    INNER JOIN trips t ON t.trip_id = st.trip_id
    INNER JOIN routes r ON r.route_id = t.route_id
    WHERE st.stop_id = <stop_id>;
```

For good performance, make sure you have `stop_times` indexed to allow fast lookups of trips by stop ID:

```
CREATE INDEX stop_times_stop_id_trip_id_index ON stop_times(stop_id, trip_id);
```

If you *haven't* defined `route_id` and `trip_id` as the primary key for their respective tables, you'll want to create indexes for those as well:

```
CREATE INDEX routes_route_id_index ON routes(route_id);
CREATE INDEX trips_trip_id ON trips(trip_id);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried the join and still receive only one route. :(

Comment: Interesting. I tested this this morning against my own dataset and got the correct result. Are you able to post the GTFS bundle (the ZIP file) somewhere for me to grab?

Comment: Yes. It's open data so I should be able to. The link is: http://www.vta.org/getting-around/gtfs-info/data-file

Comment: Great. I'll take a look at this tonight.

Comment: I too get one result: route 31. What makes you believe there is more than one route servicing this stop?

Comment: For comparison, try running the same query for stop ID 100.

Comment: Thanks for the help!! I was getting more than one route after all! I was just misreading the GTFS file. Haha